# Silverlight vs ActiveX for lightweight app with system access

Tags: silverlight, activex

Just an R&D question.  We need to develop an application that can be run in a browser that has the capability of performing some system checks to gather support information to be emailed to us.  These checks will include basic system information, but also will need to scan the filesystem and pull out version information about various DLLS, executables, and .NET assemblies that might be installed.  The idea being that we can direct a client to a page and have the application gather the relevant information needed for support, and potentially even populate some database fields. We need it to have as small a footprint as possible.

I've worked with ActiveX before, and know it is capable of these things, but particularly on modern systems security is a nightmare to get around, with a lot of people blocking ActiveX altogether.  Is Silverlight easier to deliver to clients?  Does it have a lighter footprint?  Is it even capable of doing these things?

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Silveright has access to isolated storage, but I don't think it can do what you are looking for (I may be wrong). As for footprint, if I remember correctly, the runtime is reasonably small, and the .xap packages are limited to 4Mb.</strike>

Silverlight out-of-browser has access to the file system. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd550721(v=vs.95).aspx#special_features_for_outofbrowser_applications

If you intend to run your app in the browser, you will still have to configure the trust as if it where oob. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg192793(v=vs.95).aspx

However, iTunes has a neat way of doing something somewhat related. It has a custom protocol (itms://) that allows the browser to invoke a client side program (iTunes). Then you can embed html in a webpage that passes parameters as command line arguments to that app. The website also knows if the iTunes is installed by a cookie. We this in mind, you might be able to encourage your users to install some small app that setups the custom protocol on install. You could pass command-line parameters to it from the web, and the app will push information from the client back to the server.

To create a real-time experience, you could use sockets + more javascript to update the page with the info you just got off the machine.

HTH,

Comment: We are trying to avoid an app installation, otherwise the browser wouldn't be relevant, we'd just deploy an app that did what we needed; but I get what you're saying.

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight runs in a pretty restricted silo and can't do a lot of low level things - such as checking the file system. So I would say it does not fit your use case, unfortunately.